# Conditional continuous distributions - need help understanding answer to a beginner example

Tags: probability, statistics

**Example (credit to Sheldon Ross)**

Consider $n + m$ trials having a common probability of success. Suppose, however, that this success probability is not fixed in advance but is chosen from a uniform $(0, 1)$ population. What is the conditional distribution of the success probability given that the $n + m$ trials result in $n$ successes?

**The Answer**

Given, check out screenshot below.

**My questions**

1. Is the red arrow saying that the $P(X=x) = f_X(x) = 1$ for $0<x<1$ ?
2. In general for continous conditional distributions, is the $P(Y=y) = f_Y(y)$ or something? I know this to be equal to zero but in #1 above it is equal to the density function...
3. I don't see the intuition why $P(N=n)$ does not depend on $x$. I get that you divide by the marginal distribution of $N$ which should not depend on the other joint RV... but how can you write out the $P(N=n)$ without referencing $x$...

Thank you for your insight!

---

[image]

Comment: $f_{X|N=n}(x)=\dfrac{f_{X,N}(x,n)}{f_N(n)}$

$=\dfrac{f_{N|X=x}(n)f_X(x)}{f_N(n)}=\dfrac{\mathrm{Pr}(N=n|X=x)f_X(x)}{\mathrm{Pr}(N=n)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the book I'm using it shows the first expression but not the middle that you wrote. That is illuminating. Is it accurate then to say that the $P(X=x) = f_X(x)$? Is this true in general? Not just joint distributions... also how does this fit into the fact that for a continuous RV the probability of a specific value is zero? Sorry I'm a newb.

Comment: No , it makes no sense to say that. The notation $f_Z$ has been used here to denote the density function of a continuous random variable $Z$. The same notation is replaced by $P(Z=z)$ when $Z$ is discrete.

Comment: Of course there is no harm in writing $f_Z$ to denote the pmf of $Z$ as well.

Comment: Thanks I think my hang up is that the $z$ in $P(Z=z)$ is not a constant but a variable... and so when I think of the continous analog of $P(Z=z)$ I feel this should be zero since I was taking $z$ as a constant, but it's not...

Comment: $P(Z=z)$ *is* zero whenever $Z$ is continuous. And yes, the $z$ is a dummy variable.

Comment: Ugh I think part of my problem is I've never studied the continuous case of the law of total probability. I found a paper on the internet that is helping me. In the equality of your first comment I believe you can put in a $dx$ everywhere (which gets divided out).

Comment: Okay in regards to my question 3, I think $P(N=n)$ in the denominator is equal to the integral of $P(N=n|X=x)f_x(x)dx$ from $0$ to $1$ and then the $x$ will come out of the expression.

Comment: Yes your thoughts on evaluating the denominator is correct.

Comment: Sick thanks for your help today. I feel like I learned a little bit more.